# Can't Export to Excel using Php7 and Mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, php-7

I need to import mysql datas to an excel file. I'm using php7. I wrote a code but the problem is all the data are printed in a single column in excel file. Could anyone help me with code to change the row and column in excel file.
This is my code:
       `

```
$connect=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crmweb");
$output='';$output2='';

    $sql="SELECT name,hname,cno FROM hencus ";
    $result=  mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $output.=' 
                <table class="table" border="1>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>House</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    </tr>';
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $output.=' 

                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['hname'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['cno'].'</td>
                    </tr>';

        }
        $output.='</table>';

        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
        echo $output;
       // echo $output2;


    }

    ?>      `
```

Comment: i am not very sure but this is not a legit way of excel export but can you try `xlsx` not `xls` at your header and file name extension

Comment: still not getting @Santa'shelper can you give some other method to convert? thanks in advance

Comment: There is a  PHP library called [`phpoffice/phpexcel`](https://github.com/PHPOffice)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
header ("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header ("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=download.xls");
```

instead of

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
```

[Here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php) you can find a good tutorial.

Comment: I didn't try this because i got the output .Thank you